# SearchBar.IsEnabled binding are not updated when property changed in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: data-binding, xamarin, searchbar, xamarin.forms

I want to disable searchbar whenever my viewmodel is busy.
And I have the following xaml for my view (part of view):

```xml
<SearchBar x:Name="searchBar" TextChanged="OnSearchQueryChanged" Grid.Row="0"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="progress" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
```

Both elements are bound to the the same property however SearchBar stays disabled when my ViewModel raise IsBusy = false. Same time progress becomes hidden.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is to set the `SearchBar.IsEnabled` property to `true` when you view model `IsBusy` property is `false`, and *vice versa*.

What you're doing right now, is disabling (setting `IsEnabled` to false) the search bar when the your vie model is no longer busy (`IsBusy` is false).

You need a converter for this, one that returns true for false, and false for true:

```cs
public class NotConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.GetType () == typeof(bool))
            return !((bool)value);
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

In order to use it in your binding in xaml, let's include an instance of it as a resource in the container wrapping your xaml snippet (let's assume it's a `ContentPage`), and then we can reference that converter in the `{Binding}` markup extension:

```xml
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace;assembly=YourAssemblyName">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:NotConverter x:Key="notConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar" TextChanged="OnSearchQueryChanged" Grid.Row="0"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource notConverter}}"/>
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="progress" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```